# scala - higher order functions change type T to type Nothing

Tags: scala, types, polymorphism, higher-order-functions

trouble-shooting env: sbt console (Scala 2.11.8) & spark-shell (Spark 2.3, Scala 2.11)

I have a higher-order function with a view bound type T...  but that arg `t: T` type signature turns from `T <% Double` to `Nothing` when the function is partially applied.

Toy example to demonstrate:

```
// tot: T needs to work on (at least) Int, Long, Double, Float
// no common supertype -> some kind of context bound

def func[T <% Double](isValid: Boolean)(tot: T, cnt: Int): Double = 
  if (isValid) tot.toDouble / cnt else Double.NaN
```

When I try to partially apply isValid, I'd expect the result to be type `(T, Int) => Double` but instead the type ends up `(Nothing, Int) => Double`, and I cannot pass in arg `tot`.

```
val f1 = func(true)_   // f1: (Nothing, Int) => Double = <function2>
val f2 = func(false)_  // f2: (Nothing, Int) => Double = <function2>

val g1 = f1(10.0, 1)
// <console>:40: error: type mismatch;
// found   : Double(10.0)
// required: Nothing
//       val g1 = f1(10.0, 1)
```

I'm not getting any error messages when defining f1 or f2...  so it's hard to interpret.  It just converts arg `tot: T` to type `Nothing`.

Checking scala doc...  I see scala.Nothing is a subtype of EVERY other type, so I thought maybe it was losing the view bound on T...  which was maybe related to type erasure...  so I tried using ClassTag...

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

def func[T <% Double](isValid: Boolean)(tot: T, cnt: Int)(implicit tag: ClassTag[T]): Double = 
  if (isValid) tot.toDouble / cnt else Double.NaN
```

That doesn't help.  Same problem.

if I try using `implicit num: Numeric[T]` it chokes on type `Nothing` in a new way...

```
def func[T](isValid: Boolean)(tot: T, cnt: Int)( implicit num: Numeric[T] ): Double = 
  if (isValid) num.toDouble(tot) / cnt else Double.NaN

val f1 = func(true)_
// <console>:40: error: could not find implicit value for parameter num: Numeric[Nothing]
//        val f1 = func(true)_
```

If I apply it all at once (using first 'func' at top), it works fine...

```
val g1 = func(true)(10.0, 1)
// g1: Double = 10.0
```

But in my real (non-toy) code, that's not an option.

What is happening here, and how can I make `func` work when partially applied?

**EDIT [@Alexey's solution]**

I can't get the preferred 'def' approach to work.

```
def func[T <% Double](isValid: Boolean)(tot: T, cnt: Int): Double =
  if (isValid) tot.toDouble / cnt else Double.NaN
// func: [T](isValid: Boolean)(tot: T, cnt: Int)(implicit evidence$1: T => Double)Double

def f1[T <% Double]: ((T, Int) => Double) = func[T](true)_
// f1: [T](implicit evidence$1: T => Double)(T, Int) => Double

f1[Double](10.0, 1)
<console>:41: error: too many arguments for method f1: (implicit evidence$1: Double => Double)(Double, Int) => Double
   f1[Double](10.0, 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I try to partially apply `isValid`, I'd expect the result to be type `(T, Int) => Double`

Values can't be generic. So it can have this type for some specific `T`, but you don't provide exactly the parameters which would allow inferring it. You can specify e.g.

```
val f1 = func[TheTypeYouWant](true) _
```

or

```
val f1: (TheTypeYouWant, Int) => Double = func(true) _
```

If you want it to be generic, it has to be a `def` again:

```
def f1[T <% Double] = func[T](true) _
```

Comment: Thanks Alexey!  When I try your solution, using `def f1 ...` the type signature ends up as `[T](implicit evidence$1: T => Double)(T, Int) => Double`.  I'm reading here to try and figure out what to pass as the 'implicit evidence' param:  https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/07-implicits.html#context-bounds-and-view-bounds

Comment: @kmh *you* don't have to pass anything as implicit evidence, you only have to specify the type `T`. The implicit evidence of `T` being implicitly convertible into a Double will be supplied automatically by the compiler. That's kind of the whole point of implicit parameters, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks Andrey!  When I try the 'def' approach, f1 ends up with type signature `f1: [T](implicit evidence$1: T => Double)(T, Int) => Double` which seems ok, but when I call `f1[Double](10.0, 1)` it chokes with a 'too many args for method f1', which I can't sort out.  (full error in 'edit' at bottom of orig post)

Comment: @kmh Try `f1[Double].apply(10.0, 1)`.

Comment: @kmh As Brian says. Or you can store it in a val: `val g1 = f1[Double]; g1(10.0, 1)`.